# Method 'dibujarTablero' and method 'pulsado'

Tags: java, android, method-invocation

I'm trying to make a 4 in line in Android Studio, I have to complete one method (dibujarTablero() --> drawBoard() in english), the thing is, I have to assign the correct drawable to the id depending on the status of each ring on the board, I don't know if I completed the method in the right way.

By the other hand, the method 'pulsado' is never used, I want to know where it must be called or used :/. I attach the code of the Game.java and MainActivity.java, the android code is right, I just need the java code.

Game.java

```
package android.esteban.conecta4;

/**
* Created by Esteban on 19/10/2015.
*/

import java.util.Random;

public class Game {
static final int NFILAS = 6;
static final int NCOLUMNAS = 7;
static final int VACIO = 0;
static final int MAQUINA = 1;
static final int JUGADOR = 2;

private int tablero[][];

public Game() {
    tablero = new int[NFILAS][NCOLUMNAS];

    for (int i = 0; i < NFILAS; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < NCOLUMNAS; j++)
            tablero[i][j] = VACIO;
}

/*************************************************************************
 Completa este metodo.
 Parametros: indices i y j del tablero.
 Retorno: cierto si la posicion tablero[i][j] esta vacia (su valor
 es VACIO) y falso en caso contrario
 *************************************************************************/
public boolean estaVacio(int i, int j) {
    // Aqui debes incluir tu codigo

    if(tablero[i][j] == JUGADOR){
        return false;
    }

    else {
        return true;
    }
}

/*************************************************************************
 Completa este metodo.
 Parametros: indices i y j del tablero.
 Retorno: cierto si la posicion tablero[i][j] esta ocupada por el
 jugador (su valor es JUGADOR) y falso en caso contrario
 *************************************************************************/
public boolean estaJugador(int i, int j) {

    // Aqui debes incluir tu codigo

    if(tablero[i][j] == JUGADOR){
        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void ponerJugador(int i, int j) {
    tablero[i][j] = JUGADOR;
}

public boolean tableroLleno() {
    for (int i=0; i<NFILAS; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<NCOLUMNAS; j++)
            if (tablero[i][j] == VACIO)
                return false;

    return true;
}

/*************************************************************************
 Completa este metodo.
 Parametros: indices i y j del tablero.
 Retorno: cierto si se puede colocar ficha en la posicion (i,j) del
 tablero. Debes comprobar que esa posicion del tablero esta vacia
 (su valor es VACIO) y que es la posicion vacia mas baja del tablero.
 En caso contrario, la funcion debe devolver false.
 *************************************************************************/
public boolean sePuedeColocarFicha(int i, int j) {
    // Aqui debes incluir tu codigo

    if(tablero[i][j] == VACIO){
        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void juegaMaquina() {
    int i;
    int fila = -1, columna;
    Random r = new Random();

    do {
        columna = r.nextInt(NCOLUMNAS);

        for (i = 0; i < NFILAS; i++)
            if (tablero[i][columna] == VACIO) {
                fila = i;
                break;
            }
    } while (fila < 0);

    tablero[fila][columna] = MAQUINA;
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package android.esteban.conecta4;
//Creado por Esteban Fajardo Muñoz

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final int ids[][] = {
        { R.id.primerBoton5, R.id.segundoBoton5, R.id.tercerBoton5, R.id.cuartoBoton5, R.id.quintoBoton5, R.id.sextoBoton5, R.id.septimoBoton5 },
        { R.id.primerBoton4, R.id.segundoBoton4, R.id.tercerBoton4, R.id.cuartoBoton4, R.id.quintoBoton4, R.id.sextoBoton4, R.id.septimoBoton4 },
        { R.id.primerBoton3, R.id.segundoBoton3, R.id.tercerBoton3, R.id.cuartoBoton3, R.id.quintoBoton3, R.id.sextoBoton3,
                R.id.septimoBoton3 },
        { R.id.primerBoton2, R.id.segundoBoton2, R.id.tercerBoton2, R.id.cuartoBoton2, R.id.quintoBoton2, R.id.sextoBoton2,
                R.id.septimoBoton2 },
        { R.id.primerBoton1, R.id.segundoBoton1, R.id.tercerBoton1, R.id.cuartoBoton1, R.id.quintoBoton1, R.id.sextoBoton1,
                R.id.septimoBoton1 },
        { R.id.primerBoton, R.id.segundoBoton, R.id.tercerBoton, R.id.cuartoBoton, R.id.quintoBoton, R.id.sextoBoton,
                R.id.septimoBoton } };

private Game game;
private TextView resultadoTextView;

/*************************************************************************
 Completa este metodo.
 Despues de inflar la interfaz especificada en el fichero activity_main.xml,
 este metodo debe instanciar un objeto de tipo Game y asignar la referencia
 al miembro privado game.
 *************************************************************************/
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Aqui debes incluir tu codigo
    game = new Game();
    resultadoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultadoTextView);
}

/*************************************************************************
 Completa este metodo.
 Dependiendo del estado de cada casilla del tablero, debes asignar al
 identificador id el dibujable adecuado:
 - R.drawable.c4_button
 - R.drawable.c4_human_pressed_button
 - R.drawable.c4_machine_pressed_button
 *************************************************************************/
public void dibujarTablero() {
    int id = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < Game.NFILAS; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < Game.NCOLUMNAS; j++) {

            // Aqui debes incluir tu codigo

            if(game.estaJugador(i,j) == true){
                id = R.drawable.c4_human_pressed_button;
            }

            if(game.estaVacio(i,j) == true){
                id = R.drawable.c4_button;
            }

            if(game.estaVacio(i,j) == false && game.estaJugador(i,j) == false){
                id = R.drawable.c4_machine_pressed_button;
            }

            ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(ids[i][j]);
            imageButton.setImageResource(id);
        }
}

public void pulsado(View v) {
    int fila, columna, id = v.getId();

    if (game.tableroLleno()) {
        resultadoTextView.setText(R.string.fin_del_juego);
        return;
    }

    fila = deIdentificadorAFila(id);
    columna = deIdentificadorAColumna(id);

    if (game.sePuedeColocarFicha(fila, columna) != true) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.nosepuedecolocarficha,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    game.ponerJugador(fila, columna);
    game.juegaMaquina();
    dibujarTablero();
}

private int deIdentificadorAFila(int id) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Game.NFILAS; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < Game.NCOLUMNAS; j++)
            if (ids[i][j] == id)
                return i;
    return -1;
}

private int deIdentificadorAColumna(int id) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Game.NFILAS; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < Game.NCOLUMNAS; j++)
            if (ids[i][j] == id)
                return j;
    return -1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the method sePuedeColocarFicha() you are asking if that spot tablero[i][j] is empty, but not if is the last row / the lowest position. Have you added some code to check it?

Also, in case you leave it like it, you are doing the same as in the method estaVacio (in estaVacio you should ask in the IF if that position is equal to 0/vacio, for that is called that method Vacio, you are doing the same as in esJugador) (which also checks if that position in tablero is empty)